# TYPO3 9.5 Tutorial needed

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

It might be a bit too general, but I need a reasonable tutorial on TYPO3 9.5

I just finished going through the tutorials on TYPO3 site, but to my frustration they are all but useless when it comes to simplest of questions.

For example: 
After creating a template, how do I assign content to the correct parts of the page?

And a dozen or so more of the ilk.

Some reasonable introduction to extensions in TYPO3 would be nice as well.

Honestly if it were not for the customer, I could of done 3 or four similar sites in the time it takes to work how TYPO3 works :-(

Comment: Resource requests are off-topic here.  If you have a specific question (it sounds like you do), you could ask that instead, though.

Comment: I'd have to start a 100 or so new threads at least with rather flimsy wording in each one of them. A good place to start is rather important to be able to ask the right questions in a correct way :-)

Comment: You have to illustrate your problem in detail by example. Your example "After creating a template ...": Which template do you mean? A Fluid template? Or with markers/subparts? How do you connect your template (layout or template?) to TYPO3. Via PAGE typoscript object? How does it look like. What do you mean with "correct parts of the page"? Navigation? Or just the content elements? So, if you don't precise your problem, no one can help you.

Comment: This is just an example but one of the tutorials I followed was this one
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TemplatingTutorial/Sitemap/Index.html

After creating pages with templates attached to them, the question appeared:
How do I add content to the page that is assigned to the correct part of the template?

Or
Where should I store CSS and JavaScript files?

etc etc etc

I understand that once someone had worked with any system for a while, these seem like dumb questions, but I am yet to find a tutorial that would cover those basics.

I am not looking to develop extensions just yet

Comment: I can understand your problem. Some of the Typo3 docs are akwardly written, the problem being that there is context missing - WHAT to put WHERE in order to get it running? For example the *Typoscript in 45 Minutes* (self called) tutorial does not explain where to enter the Typoscript. This gets explained in the reference, which is an unexpected place. One would think the tutorial explains these basics. However, other parts of the docs are well written, eg the mentioned ts reference or the Extbase/Fluid docs. Another issue is that most docs are not up to date with the latest Framework versions.

Comment: Compare this with for example Python. The docs are related to the Python version. All changes get documented under 'Whats new' and also in the docs for the related API element. There is a tutorial and a library and language reference. More topics after. They go from simple to difficult.There is a search function, a glossary and two indices. On the top a breadcrumb. The whole docs are sprinkled with copypastable code examples. The docs quite well reflect the 13th aphorism from the Zen of Python: 'There should be one -- and preferably only one -- obvious way to do it'.

Answer (score 1):

I had my start with TYPO3 using [Wolgang Wagners video tutorials](https://typo3-videotraining.com/typo3-8-lts). It costs 77 Euros, is in **German** language and only available for **version 7 and 8**. Most of it should still be applicable to version 9.

Comment: This guy has a nice presentation he on his youtube chanel. It doesn't teach everything but he really goes through the very basics.

A good place to start for all https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5-zqudJz0o

Answer (score 0):

As per FrankHsnblg suggestion feel free to check it out.

The guy Frank advised has a nice tutorial on his Youtube channel that should get most of the people started.

I could understand it even with some rather basic German knowledge

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5-zqudJz0o

Answer (score 0):

If you know German, I suggest to you these tutorials.

[Daniel macht TYPO3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QCF78RSgtkA&list=PL1D69sw7eWECaiqIOLhcSnjgTTjLJdd4I)

Even tho Daniel is using version 7.6, you will learn a lot.

Have fun :)

Comment: Will give them a shot as well :-)